# appcelerator dexer fails with Uncaught translation error when using module

Tags: android, module, appcelerator

Using Appcelerator with Titanium SDK 6.2.2.GA (the same happens with any 6.x SDK).
I create a new project module, compile it (for 6.2.2) and install it in the SDK (6.2.2).
Then I create a new Mobile App project (Clasic, Single Window, No Cloud) and add the previously created module to it.
I compile to run and the result is :

```
[ERROR] :  Failed to run dexer:
[ERROR] :  
[ERROR] :  Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/compat/R;
[ERROR] :  Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/compat/R$anim;
[ERROR] :  Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/compat/R$animator;
[ERROR] :  Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/compat/R$attr;
[ERROR] :  Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/compat/R$bool;
[ERROR] :  Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/compat/R$color;
[ERROR] :  Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/compat/R$dimen;
[ERROR] :  Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/compat/R$drawable;
[ERROR] :  Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/compat/R$id;
[ERROR] :  
[ERROR] :  UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
[ERROR] :  java.lang.RuntimeException: Translation has been interrupted
[ERROR] :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:608)
[ERROR] :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMultiDex(Main.java:366)
[ERROR] :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:275)
[ERROR] :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
[ERROR] :   at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
[ERROR] :  Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException: Too many errors
[ERROR] :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:600)
[ERROR] :   ... 4 more
```

I have tried :
Other Java versions
Other android build tools versions

When doing the same with SDK 5.x.x.GA it works fine. The problem started when I installed Axway Appcelerator Studio, build: 4.10.0.201709271713 and attempted to compile my project with Titanium SDK 6.2.2.GA. (Before I was using 5.x.x).

Any ideas welcome.

Comment: what build tools version do you have? And what is your build target version?

Comment: Build tools is 23.0.3 but I have also tried 25. My module build.properties are titanium.platform=C:\\ProgramData\\Titanium\\mobilesdk\\win32\\6.2.2.GA\\android
android.platform=C:\\android-sdk-win\\platforms\\android-25
google.apis=C:\\android-sdk-win\\add-ons\\addon-google_apis-google-25
android.ndk=C:\\android-ndk-r10d and my app SDK target is 6.2.2.GA

Answer (score 0):

Version `6.2.2.GA` requires you to use Android SDK 26 and build tools 26. Before 6.2 you needed build tools 23.

You can force a version in the `tiapp.xml` file in the android manifest section

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="23"/>
```

As always, check the [Compatibilty matrix of Titanium](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Titanium_Compatibility_Matrix-section-src-29004837_safe-id-VGl0YW5pdW1Db21wYXRpYmlsaXR5TWF0cml4LUFuZHJvaWRTREsvVGFyZ2V0QW5kcm9pZFBsYXRmb3Jt)

Comment: I have tried to complile for SDK 6.0.3 but the result is exaclty the same. Also I have checked the module build path and it is correct.

Comment: 6.0.3 SDK requires build tools 23, not 26

Answer (score 0):

After uninstalling Appcelerator Studio, reinstalling and setting the path for NDK to use android-ndk-r11c and also installing GNU gperf the problem is fixed.

Comment: In the end this did not work permanently. I works when using ant but after using Publish in SDK for some reason the errror reapears. I think the best solution is to dump appcelerator all together because it suffers for so many bugs that is is unusable. I think it better to invest my time into porting my code to Xamarin than searching for days for a way to build my project.